# Structural topic modeling - compare groups (issue ranking)

Tags: topic-models

I am trying to compare two groups (liberal news, conservative news articles) after running a structural topic modeling. I first did a structural topic modeling of the whole news article and got a document-topic-matrix. Now, I am trying to see the frequency of topics for each group (i.e., to understand the issue ranking of conservative and liberal media—that is, the frequency of each issue by each group of media).

Does anyone have any idea about how to compare two groups? (I have a variable that distinguishes each media into either liberal (=1) or conservative (=2).)

Someone suggested: estimateEffect() and tried it, but it showed the Coefficients of groups (liberal/conservative media) on each topic, not the issue ranking of each media.

I’d appreciate any comments!